# Is manual acknowledgment of IModel thread-safe in RabbitMq .net client?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, thread-safety

As noted in [.net Api guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#model-sharing) operations over `IModel` instance are not thread-safe.

> As a rule of thumb, `IModel` instances should not be used by more than
>   one thread simultaneously: application code should maintain a clear
>   notion of thread ownership for `IModel` instances. If more than one
>   thread needs to access a particular `IModel` instances, the application
>   should enforce mutual exclusion itself. One way of achieving this is
>   for all users of an `IModel` to  lock the instance itself.

And then code example is displayed as a way to enforce mutual exclusion  while publishing.

```
IModel ch = RetrieveSomeSharedIModelInstance();
lock (ch) {
  ch.BasicPublish(...);
}
```

So far, so good. And then some symptoms of incorrect serialisation of `IModel` operations are explained. However they noted that, ***symptoms are not limited to those operations***. That part of the sentence really creates some questions in our mind. Is manual acknowledgment thread-safe or not? Do we have to use some lock before acking inside `EventingBasicConsumer`'s `Received` event handler or not?

There is some [github issue](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/issues/145) opened for clarification of that point, but they found no answer and recommended to the OP to ask question in SO, which I wasn't able to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only be safe if you ack [one message at a time](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#consumer-acks-double-acking). I would avoid sharing channels entirely when possible.

Comment: Could you please add exact phrase from that article?

Comment: It is clearly stated: "As a rule of thumb, IModel instances should not be used by more than one thread simultaneously".